# Parsing a Hierarchy in a String Value

Tags: r

I am trying to create an edge list from a single character vector. My list to be processed is over 93k elements long, but as an example I will provide a small excerpt.

The chracter strings are part of the ICD10 code hierarchy and the parent child relationships exist within the string. That means that a single string, "A0101", would have a parent of "A010"

It would look like this:

- A00

  - A000
  - A001
  - A009
- A01

  - A010

    - A0100
    - A0101
- A02
- A03
- etc.

My vector does not contain any other data except the strings but i basically need to convert

```
dat <- c("A00", "A000", "A001", "A009", "A01", "A010", "A0100", "A0101", "A02")
```

into an edge list formatted as follows...

```
# (A00, A000)
# (A00, A001)
# (A00, A009)
# (A01, A010)
# (A010, A0100)
# (A010, A0101)
```

Comment: Hi Trip, what's the logic for converting the list to the edgelist? At first I thought A00-A000 is first edge, A001-A009 is second edge, A01-A010 is third edge, but the example output looks different. Thanks :)

Comment: I could be mistaken in my thinking but I am trying to create a hierarchical data format that I can then use to measure distances between individual nodes on the tree.   The values represent ICD10 diagnosis values and I am trying to measure similarity of sets of diagnosis codes.

Comment: Oh, that's really interesting. I think the person below got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am fairly certain there are more efficient ways to accomplish this but this excerpt of code should download the ICD10 CM data from the icd.data package. Use the children detection system from the icd package and then make extensive use of the tidyverse to return an edgelist.  I had to get a bit creative to connect the "top" of the hierarchies since they do not include the chapters and sub chapters of ICD10 data as an individual 2 or 1 digit code.

Basically sub-chapters become 2 digit codes, chapters become 1 digit codes, and then there is a root node to connect everything at the top.

```
library(icd.data)
icd10 <- icd10cm2016

library(icd)
code_children <- lapply(icd10$code, children)

code_vec <- sapply(code_children, paste, collapse = ",")
code_df <- as.data.frame(code_vec, stringsAsFactors = F)

library(dplyr);library(stringr);library(tidyr)

code_df_new <- code_df %>% 
  mutate(parent = sapply(strsplit(code_vec,","), "[", 1)) %>%
  separate(code_vec, 
    paste("code", 1:max(str_count(code_df$code_vec, ",")), sep ="."),
    ",",extra = "merge")

library(reshape2)

edgelist <- melt(code_df_new, id = "parent") %>% 
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  select(parent, child = value) %>%
  arrange(parent)

edgelist <- subset(edgelist, edgelist$parent != edgelist$child)
edgelist <- subset(edgelist, nchar(edgelist$child) == nchar(edgelist$parent) + 1)

subchaps <- icd10 %>% select(three_digit, sub_chapter, chapter) %>%
  mutate(two_digit = substr(three_digit, 1, 2)) %>%
  select(parent = two_digit, child = three_digit) %>%
  distinct()

chaps <- icd10 %>% select(three_digit, sub_chapter, chapter) %>%
  mutate(
    two_digit = substr(three_digit, 1, 2), 
    one_digit = substr(three_digit, 1, 1)) %>%
  select(parent = one_digit, child = two_digit) %>%
  distinct()

root <- icd10 %>% select(three_digit) %>%
  mutate(parent = "root", child = substr(three_digit, 1, 1)) %>%
  select(parent, child) %>%
  distinct()

edgelist_final <- edgelist %>%
  bind_rows(list(chaps, subchaps, root)) %>%
  arrange(parent)
```

If anybody has any tips or methods to improve the efficiency of this code I am all ears. (eyes?)

Comment: I'm interested in what the goal of this work is. Maybe we could connect?

Comment: Hi @JackWasey ...the goal was to utilize this method to calculate "distances" in the icd ontology. here have been some published papers on the topic of calculating patient similarity based on their "bag" of diagnoses.

Comment: This is interesting, but I have sought and not found any publications in this area which do not use comorbidities. Would you point me towards some, please?

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that the length of the node names in ICD10 fully define the order (with shorter ones being parents), here's an approach that connects each node with it's immediate parent, if available.

While I think the logic is legible here, I'd be curious to see what a more streamlined solution would look like.

```
# Some longer fake data to prove that it works acceptably
#   with 93k rows (took a few seconds). These are just
#   numbers of different lengths, converted to characters, but they 
#   should suffice if the assumption about length = order is correct.
set.seed(42)
fake <- runif(93000, 0, 500) %>% 
  magrittr::raise_to_power(3) %>% 
  as.integer() %>% 
  as.character()


# Step 1 - prep
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)
fake_2 <- fake %>%
  as_data_frame() %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%

  # Step 2 - widen by level and fill in all parent nodes
  mutate(level = str_length(value)) %>%
  spread(level, value) %>%
  fill(everything()) %>%

  # Step 3 - Get two highest non-NA nodes
  gather(level, code, -row) %>%
  arrange(row, level) %>%
  filter(!is.na(code)) %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  top_n(2, wt = level) %>%

  # Step 4 - Spread once more to get pairs
  mutate(pos = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-level) %>%
  spread(pos, code)
```

Output on OP data

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
    row `1`   `2`  
  <int> <chr> <chr>
1     1 A00   NA   
2     2 A00   A000 
3     3 A00   A001 
4     4 A00   A009 
5     5 A01   A009 
6     6 A01   A010 
7     7 A010  A0100
8     8 A010  A0101
9     9 A010  A0101
```

Output on 93k fake data

```
> head(fake, 10)
 [1] "55174190" "50801321" "46771275" "6480673" 
 [5] "20447474" "879955"   "4365410"  "11434009"
 [9] "5002257"  "9200296" 

> head(fake_2, 10)
# A tibble: 10 x 3
     row `1`      `2`     
   <int> <chr>    <chr>   
 1     1 55174190 NA      
 2     2 50801321 NA      
 3     3 46771275 NA      
 4     4 6480673  46771275
 5     5 6480673  20447474
 6     6 6480673  20447474
 7     7 4365410  20447474
 8     8 4365410  11434009
 9     9 5002257  11434009
10    10 9200296  11434009
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the assumption on chracter length is not sufficient. Shorter codes are the parent nodes of that code with an appended chracter, but the root string has to match...

In other words A0101 is the child of A010 but not A011

That code worked beautifully otherwise, but that may have been my mistake in not explaining the hierarchy of ICD10 appropriately.